# Vim goes to insert mode when I run easymotion search

Tags: vim, plugins, vi

I have easymotion highlighting lines below and above (leader-j, leader-k). When I press leader-s to launch the easymotion character search vim enters insert mode. My leader is set to `\` btw.

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Running Vim 7.4.903

Comment: Use the plugin's issue tracker.

Comment: Good idea @romainl Done: https://github.com/easymotion/vim-easymotion/issues/286